# Matrix in methos

Tags: java

If I have a partially filled 2D matrix from user input, how can I fill it in some other void method to get spiral matrix:
Here is my code: However, when I run it the dimensions of matrix still remain 1000X1000. How can I fix this problem? I need to have only two methods - fillSpiral and main. The program should get any square matrix from user then change its values in a way it becomes a spiral matrix.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Spiral {
    public static void fillSpiral(int matrix[][]) {
            int row1 = 0, row2 = matrix.length, col1 = 0, col2 = matrix[0].length;
            int num = 1;
            while (num <= matrix.length) {
                for (int col = col2-1; col >= col1; col--){
                    matrix[row2-1][col] = num;
                    num++;
                }
                for (int row = row2-2; row >= row1; row--) {
                    matrix[row][col1] = num;
                    num++;
                }
                for (int col = col1+1; col < col2; col++) {
                    matrix[row1][col] = num;
                    num++;
                }
                for (int  row = row1+1; row < row2-1; row++) {
                    matrix[row][col2-1] = num;
                    num++;
                }
                row1++;
                row2--;
                col1++;
                col2--;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%12d", matrix[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 0;
        int[][] matrixOutput = new int[1000][1000];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int i=0; i<matrixOutput.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<matrixOutput[0].length; j++){
                    while (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
                    matrixOutput[i][j] = keyboard.nextInt();
                    n++;
                    }
                }
            }
        fillSpiral(matrixOutput);
    }
}
```

example

> ```
> Input
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
>
> Output
> 5 6 7
> 4 9 8
> 3 2 1
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't [goggled](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/01/leetcode-spiral-matrix-java/#:~:text=Given%20a%20matrix%20of%20m%20x%20n%20elements,form%20a%20circle%20and%20we%20process%20the%20circle.) it? I see a [lot](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/) of examples [everywhere](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-program-to-print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form)

Comment: The problem is that I need to use a partially filled matrix in order to get a user input.

Answer (score 0):

Since the algorithm for an spiral matrix is not new i assume your only problem is to read a matrix of an fixed size. Then addressing only your main method use this

```
    //i preferr buffered reader over scanner
    try(BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
    {
     ArrayList<String> rows=new ArrayList();

     String line=null;      
     do
     {
       //example 1,2,3,4,5
      System.out.println("Enter an row for this matrix all elements , seperated or an empty string to end input");
    
      line=reader.readLine().trim();
    
      if(!(line.isEmpty() || line.isBlank())){rows.add(line);}
      else{line=null;}
     }
     while(line!=null);
    
     //i assume a square matrix so rows=columns
     int n=rows.size();
    
     int[][] matrix=new int[n][n];
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
      //split at comma to get columns
      String[] columns=rows.get(i).split(",");
     
      //assign each column to the ith row
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){matrix[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(columns[j]);}
     }

     fillSpiral(matrix);
    }
```